# Android CMake : System goes out of memory when building large project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I am working on an `Android` native project which has to compile a lot of `C++` files. I am using `CMake` to build native libs. As there are lot of `C++` source files, my system goes out of memory(IDE is using 5-6 GB memory).

Is there a settings for `build.gradle` to use less memory or any alternative to build native lib for android?